# Wget for Windows error: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)."

Tags: wget

I downloaded the Wget for Windows binary from here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

I can't execute it without getting the following bizarre error:
"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

Doesn't matter whether I put it in /Program Files or in /Program Files(x86), doesn't matter whether I run as administrator. Doesn't matter whether I run it from cmd (after creating the environment variable) or just double click the icon.

Comment: any use? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96035692-9a50-40d4-a7d3-48bda87d11ec/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b-click-ok-to-close-the-application-when

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b     really there is a lot about that error

Answer (score 1):

Also download and unzip "Dependencies" into same folder where you put the wget.exe from

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

You will then have some lib*.dll files as well as wget.exe in the same folder and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

1. Open your command prompt(Click Start then in the Search bar type `cmd` and the command prompt box will appear).
2. Once the command prompt box appears type `chkdsk C: /R` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Now it will scan and attempt to fix any file errors on your computer.

You can also use your Windows Disc(if you have one) to repair any errors.